# arguments of json.parse function in javascript are not understandable

Tags: javascript, json

I am looking at javascript file on this [page](https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/). It has a piece of code.

```
let source = fs.readFileSync("contracts.json");
let contracts = JSON.parse(source)["contracts"];
```

what does the JSON.parse function does exactly here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: It's parsing the JSON string into an object. What's confusing about it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in this case the `JSON.parse` It convert the `source` file (contracts.json) to json object and `JSON.parse("contracts.json")["contracts"]` It gives you the key **contracts** value. 
You can type the code as follows :

```
let json_obj= JSON.parse(source);
let contracts = json_obj["contracts"];
```